# React-Native mudando cor do ícone sozinho

Tags: react-native

Estou implementando um daqueles botões de "olhinho" que permite que o usuário visualize sua senha para conferir se está certa, o botão já está funcionando conforme esperado, o problema é que o ícone do botão por algum motivo está sendo exibido em azul e o arquivo que estou carregando é branco. Já tentei carregar outro ícone, e passar a propriedade `tintColor` mas a cor permanece azul.

Aqui está o meu código atual:

```
import { TextField } from 'react-native-ui-lib'

const getPasswordIconSource = visibility =>
      visibility
        ? require('@assets/images/visibility_off_white.png')
        : require('@assets/images/visibility_white.png')

console.log(properties.placeholderTextColor)

return (
  <TextField
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoComplete="password"
    autoCorrect={false}
    blurOnSubmit
    floatOnFocus
    floatingPlaceholder
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onChangeText={onChange}
    onFocus={handleFocus}
    ref={handleReference}
    returnKeyType="done"
    rightButtonProps={
      showPasswordIcon
        ? {
            iconSource: getPasswordIconSource(showPassword),
            onPress: () => setShowPassword(!showPassword),
            tintColor: properties.placeholderTextColor,
            style: { tintColor: properties.placeholderTextColor },
          }
        : null
    }
    secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
    style={[styles.input, properties.style]}
    textContentType="password"
    {...properties}
    {...inputProperties}
  />
    )
  }
)
```

Como meu ícone está sendo exibido : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como meu ícone deveria ser exibido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

output:

`console.log(properties.placeholderTextColor):` **#ffffff**

Alguém sabe como fazer o ícone ser exibido com a cor real ou como alterar a cor do ícone ?

Obs: O ícone esta em formato .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não encontrei nada na documentação (https://z448401921.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/uilib-docs/public/docs/TextField/),

Mas pelos exemplos publicados lá no github deles (https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib/blob/master/demo/src/screens/componentScreens/InputsScreen.js), o exemplo que tem esse caso utiliza a prop `iconColor`:

```
<TextField
            text70
            containerStyle={{marginBottom: INPUT_SPACING, width: 210}}
            floatingPlaceholder
            placeholder="Multiline & right button"
            multiline
            rightButtonProps={{iconSource: richText, onPress: this.onPressInfo, iconColor: Colors.red30}}
          />
```

Se trocar o `tintColor` e `style` para `iconColor` deve resolver, aí ficaria assim:

```
...
rightButtonProps={
      showPasswordIcon
        ? {
            iconSource: getPasswordIconSource(showPassword),
            onPress: () => setShowPassword(!showPassword),
            iconColor: properties.placeholderTextColor,
          }
        : null
    }
...
```